# unable to group date and field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to group date and name field then finding the count of each day.I am not able to differentiate date and time so My approach is doing the grouping based on date as well time in ISO format.

My approach:-

```
db.getCollection('blog').aggregate([
            { "$group": {
              "_id": {"name":"$name","date":"$date"},
              "Count": {
                "$sum": {
                  "$sum": "$Count"
                }
              }
            }},
            { "$project": {
              "name": "$_id",
              "Count": "$Count",
              "_id": 0
            }}
          ]).toArray()
```

input:-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "Count" : 4 , "name" : Ram, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "Count" : 4, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-01-08T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "Count" :2 , "name" : Ram, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "Count" : 2, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-01-08T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "Count" : 6, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-01-08T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "Count" : 6, "name" : Shyam, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-09T00:00:00Z")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7"), "count" : 1, "name" : Shyam, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("8"), "loginID" : 2, "name" : Arjun, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-08T00:00:00Z") }
```

Expected output:-

```
{
name:Ram,
Count:6,
date:2017-02-01
}
{
name: Arjun,
Count:12,
date:2017-02-08
}
{
name: Arjun,
Count:2,
date:2017-01-08
}
....Something like that
```

Comment: Have you tried anyhting yet?

Comment: yes I have tried.

Comment: Yeah but... What have you tried ?

Comment: I have added my approach.Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$sum` twice in your `$group` stage, you only need it once.

```
db.getCollection('blog').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        date: "$date"
      },
      Count: {
        $sum: "$Count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$_id.name",
      date: "$_id.date",
      Count: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```